# Is "what a terrible thing must be..." a common expression? Is there another one used more frequently?

Tags: expressions

Is it common to say, for example,

> What a terrible thing must be for an earthquake to hit right on your birthday.

I searched the phrase *"what a terrible thing must be..."* and got 0 results. So I assume there's another way to say this?

Comment: *What a terrible thing **it** must be ...*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to be *what a terrible thing **it** must be.*